# How to preserve leading white space while reading yaml

Tags: java, yaml, javabeans, whitespace, indentation

I am reading yaml file with YamlReader(yamlbeans.YamlReader)

```
- tag: xyz
  description: |  
    This is multi-line comment and I want to preserve  
    leading white spaces and new line
```

When I reads the above as given below:

```
String descr = tag.get("description");
```

It gives below output:

```
This is multi-line comment and I want to preserve  
leading white spaces and new line
```

But I want to preserve leading white space.

Comment: According to the YAML specifiation, there is no leading whitespace on the value for the key `description` in your YAML file. Therefore there is nothing to preserve.

Answer (score 10):

Use an indentation indicator:

```
- tag: xyz
  description: |1
     This is a multi-line comment and I want to preserve
     leading white spaces and new line
```

The `1` states that the following block scalar will have *one* space of additional indentation (in addition to the current indentation level) This will give:

```
  This is a multi-line comment and I want to preserve
  leading white spaces and new line
```

As you see, the two spaces present after the one indentation space in the block scalar are preserved. You can use any one-digit number as indentation indicator.

If you want to preserve trailing newline characters, use `|1+`, where `+` tells YAML to preserve trailing newline characters.